# `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)` throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, image, android-contentresolver

I use this intent to let user select a photo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
                           MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_SELECT_PHOTO);
```

And in `onActivityResult`:

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

But it throws `FileNotFoundException` on some android devices.

The value of `uri`:

```
content://media/external/images/media/26467
```

The exception thrown:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
```

And it's very strange that it won't throw this exception on some other android devices. What will cause this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

for images on the local device or

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
```

for images on the SD card.

Are you sure you are addressing both correctly? The internal/external treatment varies with device, maybe that is why its working on some but not on others.

Comment: I just found that because the actual images are deleted, but they have caches in the photo viewer application.

Comment: Good to know, searching for problem i ran into something that explains a related issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12508

Comment: Right Freewind, I had this exact code/error browsing my download folder for a .txt file and there where to downloads and both were about the same size, one worked one did not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem but I resolved it by using the setImageURI method of the ImageView.

You dont have to use the following code:

```
InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

Simply use the following function:

```
imageViewCustomer.setImageURI(data.getData());
```

Answer (score -2):

Use  Context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri);