# Register Activity To Open Any File With Certain Extension

Tags: android, android-intent

I've been working on an application which is set to open a file with a specific extension. It works some times with Gmail (some files open, while some don't), and I can open a file from the file explorer.

I can't open the files from the Email application on the phone however and as I say, some files do not open from the Gmail application with my application and some do!

Here is my code.

```
             <intent-filter > <!-- Solution from @richardlegget on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148629/intent-filter-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-apps-on-android -->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
             </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
             </intent-filter>
```

**My Question**

Is there a blanket set of intent-filters that register a specific activity with any file containing the desired file extension from anywhere on the Android device?

Comment: Well, this has a space between the dot and the extension and will never match anything: `android:pathPattern=".*\\. myextension"`

Comment: Sorry typo when posting the question

Comment: Have you tried closing the mail application before opening the other?

Comment: @suufang yes I have tried that. Also tried rebooting between, no luck

Comment: post your source code

Comment: This is my source code?

Comment: @DiscoS2 Do you know the mime type of the file?

Comment: @DiscoS2 please show the complete `activity` tag, not just `intent-filter` flags.

Comment: The mime type can vary as its basically a zip file with a separate extension and therefore we can't rely on it. Sometimes its `ourapp/ourfileextension' other times its 'application/zip' and then other times its 'application/octet-stream'

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why are you using separate intent-filters when you can do it using a single tag.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
        </intent-filter>
```

There might be a permissions problem. I.E If your activity is set to open in separate task, then cannot access files created/owned by other applications. You'l have to set intent flags such that it opens in the same application.

Comment: No doesn't work. The reason I am creating separate tags for each intent-filter is because they don't work when just inside one.

Comment: I have made an edit, please see if it helps. I.E. you have to remove NEW_TASK intent flag from your activity, if it is there.

Answer (score 2):

Try multiple `<data android:pathPattern/>` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4621284/23028) suggests

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve your path yourself when the `scheme` is `content`, i.e. when you receive a `URI` to a `ContentProvider`. The system will look at the mime type for your by call to `ContentResolver.getType(Uri uri)` before your intent filter is checked, hence you need the code below.

Resolve the file path to your file by fetching a Cursor from the URI containing content scheme and query the _data column:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(URI, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx);
}
```

And add this intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:mimeType="ourapp/ourfileextension" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/zip" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This will just open all files with the scheme `content`

Comment: @DiscoS2 yes, have you verified my statement about that you're trying to open URI pointing to content URI from gmail/email ?

Comment: I have used this approach before. I know how some of the content is provided as a URI however I am still no closer to understanding how to just open my file type

Comment: Then how do you know that the file that the Content provider is pointing to is actually the file with correct file ending without doing the code above?

Comment: I don't hence the question. I don't want to provide my application to be allowed to open every file type and then check in the app

Comment: @DiscoS2 Ok, test and see if my revised answer can help you

Answer (score 1):

- Can open any type of file. But here i handled repeatedly used file types, without disturbing default behaviour.
- And the snippet is as below...

  ```
  public void openAllFiles(File url) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    File file=url;
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    // Check what kind of file you are trying to open, by comparing the url with extensions.
    // When the if condition is matched, plugin sets the correct intent (mime) type,
    // so Android knew what application to use to open the file
    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    } else {
        //if you want you can also define the intent type for any other file

        //additionally use else clause below, to manage other unknown extensions
        //in this case, Android will show all applications installed on the device
        //so you can choose which application to use
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent); 
  }
  ```