# How to trigger android app from my website's button click

Tags: android, service, android-developer-api

I want to make an android app. in this app i want to control all the functionality from my website.t like if i click on a button from my website  then it trigger my app and start a service from website.

last few days i spent lots of time to search the answer of my question if anyone can help me then please tell me the process how to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with GCM

**Steps:**

1. Create admin panel with your requirements.
2. Register your app for GCM.
3. When certain action is performed then push the GCM.
4. Your app automatically received this GCM.
5. You can pass custom keyvalued json with GCM.
6. So according to this perform operation in your app.
7. Your app receive GCM even app has been killed so in background.

PS: you can also use FCM.

[Link for GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

[Link for FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Tell me if you face any probelm in this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe one way is when you click on `button` some dummy file with specific Extension (like `.egn` ) downloaded and try to opened. also register your Activity To Open that kind of files.

[Register Activity To Open Any File With Certain Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529745/register-activity-to-open-any-file-with-certain-extension)

I didn't test this solution but logically it is posible.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a custom connection from your device to the website and when the button is clicked you have to store this on the server, let the code handling your device connection then check for this data and send it on to the device, which will have to actively process the data coming from the connection you established to the server and then have the App react appropriately. 
It will take a **lot** of custom connection handling to make this possible.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me some hint how it is possible. if you have any example related with this query