# Intent Filter to Download Files In Android

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-download-manager

I'm trying to make my app appear in this screen:
[Download Apps List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mifpx.png)

So that I can download files using my app.. I added the following Intent filter into my manifest:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*.ext" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But this has no effect at all.. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution for the same?

Comment: Did you find a sensible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To use `android:host` and `android:pathPattern`, you need `android:scheme` as well.

Comment: I added <data android:scheme="content" /> but didn't work

Comment: @MuhammadA.Hassan: There is little point in using `path`/`pathPrefix`/`pathPattern` with `content`, as you have no idea what the paths will look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `intent-filter` to this one :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="file" /> //or content
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ext" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: this doesn't work.. should i declare the intent filter inside an activity or receiver ?

Comment: Yes, put it inside an Activity

Comment: Also check it out this questions and answers : [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148629/intent-filter-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-apps-on-android), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148629/intent-filter-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-apps-on-android).

Comment: I did all of that and checked the questions above but still not working. also tried changing pathPattern to ".*.ext" but didn't work neither