# Chromebook, Intent filter to download attachment from gmail apps on Android apps

Tags: android-intent, chromebook

I have an intent implementation in my Android app, accordingly to a similar solution as this: 
[Intent filter to download attachment from gmail apps on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148629/intent-filter-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-apps-on-android) **Works fine in phones and tablets but not in my Chromebook.**

I am in internal test level over Google play with my app and testing a very complete version of the app (before actual launching). It works real good on Android Phones and Tablets. So it does in my Chromebook that I am able to test now when apps can be downloaded from Google play. **But there is one exception, Intent filter to download attachment from gmail apps on the Chromebook.**

- One of the major features with my app is that users should be able to mail each other work files, like an accountant to a client to be able to browse the accounting in a mobile phone. **This works in Phones and tablets, but not in the Chromebook**

  - My file extensions (that my app supports) are *.se, *.si, *.sie, *.xgl.xml, and *ros.xml (and also .xml). The file formats comes from DOS and Windows environments and MIME is not a part of it, file extensions are. I personally think the intent list is a bit long to cover it in the phones and tablets, but it works, see below.
  - Works fine in Phones and Tablets, suggesting among others my app.
  - The Chromebook has no suggestions on Android apps, not even the ES File Explorer File manager. Just some other apps and refers to the Google play store for getting others?
- It works in the Chromebook over other android apps (open the app and start a file form storage) like the ES File Explorer File manager, but not over chrome gmail or chrome web-browser as it does in Phones and Tablets.

Question is what to do?

- Are there special intents needed for a Chromebook?
- I have been browsing over Google search as well as SOF and haven't found much.

  - There are somthing like action android:name="org.chromium.arc.intent.action.CREATE_NOTE" but I can't find any documentation of it or org.chromium.arc.intent?

Here is my present intent filter setting:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

How do I make my intents work in Chromebooks?

Comment: It works with the android gmail app in Chromebooks, but not using Chrome using the web-interface. It works with the Chrome app in android, I think it is a Chrome in Chromebooks issue.