# How do I determine the MimeType that was used by GMail to pass a file that was received by my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, intentfilter

I have an app that's supposed to handle my custom data-type `.xyz`. I'm currently using the intent filter:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "application/*", DataPathPattern = "*.xzy")]
```

On a Pixel 2 with Android 9.0 GMail automatically opens `.xyz` files when I click on that attachment. Unfortunately, my app also receives `.doc` files which it can't handle appropriately.

How do look at the MimeType that gets passed to me by an app like GMail to see which mimetype was passed for to me that I can filter less general?

Comment: you could do here is associate with "application/octet-stream", but that's not really a good user experience either.you couldn't rely on it being set correctly

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT : When I set `application/octet-stream` I can't open the files from Gmail. Gmail seems to use something else.

Comment: you could look at this link,maybe you could get some ideas:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148629/intent-filter-to-download-attachment-from-gmail-apps-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can log this information via:

```
Log.Debug(TAG, "Mimetype:'" + Intent.Type + "'");
```